# Is wind commonly formally defined as some combination of breezes, weather fronts, and climate?

Tags: wind

In a book I read, I believe the author defined wind as the sum of *breezes*, *weather*, and *climate*.

- **breezes**: hyper-local disturbances, due to topology or uneven heating of surfaces
- **weather**: the movement of air due to regional atmospheric highs and lows
- **climate**: the steady state air movement linked to, e.g., latitude

*The sum of these three vector fields is the true wind at any given moment, at any given spot.*

Two questions:

1. Is this definition correct?
2. Is this definition in common use?

Comment: Which book was this? Please [edit](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/23948/is-wind-commonly-formally-defined-as-some-combination-of-breezes-weather-fronts) it into your answer.

Comment: @Spencer, apologies but I have no recollection. This was years ago that I read it. But it was beautifully simple so the gist of things stuck with me.

Comment: This is the first time I come across such definitions used this way. In a broad sense, there's an element of truth to them, but there's also much more to it.

Comment: It is kind of as if saying your velocity is combination of where you are supposed to be going, where you are reporting you are going and where you are actually going.